# Cannot find "Theme.Material" in android studio

Tags: android, android-theme

When I create a new Project in Android Studio, the dafault app theme is "Theme.appCompat.light". Whene I try to set "Theme.Material" as theme in the manifest Android Studio shows me no suggestion, and finds no "Theme.Material". I updated everything in the sdk manager. What have I to do to use Material Theme?

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: Did you download the API Level 21 SDK? Are you targetting it? Did you reference the support library v7?

Answer (score 6):

To be able to use all of `Theme.Material` you should:

1. Make sure `compileSdkVersion` is set to at least 21.
2. Make sure that in your `dependencies` you have `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'`

Both of these can be found on your `build.gradle (Module: app)` file.

After that you can apply Material Theme simply by going to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and inside `<application>` tag make sure you have a line that says `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"`.

Comment: my problem was "@android:style/" which it first was "@style/"

Answer (score 3):

It won't show up if you just use `@style/Theme.Material` like with how you'd normally use `@style/Theme.AppCompat`.

`Theme.Material` requires you to use `@android:style/Theme.Material`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `compileSdkVersion` in the `android` closure needs to be 21 or higher to reference `Theme.Material`.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have API version below 21 in the AS editor, the material dark and light theme sections will be empty in the select theme window that pops up when trying to change theme for a specific layout.